# How to enumerate a list in portions (to avoid OutOfMemoryException)?

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading, ienumerable, out-of-memory

I have an `IEnumerable` of objects which I want to do some processing on. But when the collection gets too large, it throws an `OutOfMemoryException` upon enumerating it, for instance on a call to `Count()`.

The obvious solution is to split the collection into multiple parts so that each part is not too large. But I don't know what an ideal amount of objects in each part would be, and I want to avoid "magic numbers" because I don't know the potential size of each object. I don't even know if splitting it into multiple parts is a good solution in the first place. Any ideas?

edit:

In my code I have this function. Note the `Select` projects the `MyData` into a collection of wrapper objects which adds to the size. When this collection is enumerated, I get the exception (I could do `messages.Select(m => new CloudQueueMessage(m.ToBinary())).ToList()` to get the exception immediately).

```
    public static void AddMessages(IEnumerable<MyData> messages)
    {
        DoStuff(messages.Select(m => new CloudQueueMessage(m.ToBinary())));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [Batch](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) extension method from MoreLINQ, which is "*Batches the source sequence into sized buckets*". Example is given below:

```
int batchSize = 1000;

var lotsOfItems = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000);
var batched = lotsOfItems.Batch(batchSize); 

foreach (var batch in batched)
{
    //handle each batch
}
```

Comment: @DavidS. I've extracted it into variable, but it really depends on your solution. If you would like to have fixed-sized batches of compute their size at run-time

Comment: Thanks.. I'm afraid computing size at run-time could be the only way.

Answer (score 3):

`Enumerable.Count()` does enumerate the sequence to get it's count if it's a query and not a collection(then it's using the `Count` property). However, even if it enumerates the sequence it's should not throw an `OutOfMemoryException` since it doesn't create something new.

I assume that you are using an "unmaterialized" query which gets executed on `Count()`. You would get the exception also if you would use `ToList()` or `ToArray()`. So you need need to show us the query and we could try to optimize it in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: @David: Where's the `Count()` which you have mentioned? Where are you calling `AddMessages`, what is the input sequnce `messages`? What does `DoStuff`, what does `ToBinary()`? Too many open questions.

Comment: Alright I did not think that would be relevant, this could apply to many situations. The abstract reason for the exception is that the collection gets larger on enumeration. I call `Count()` inside `DoStuff()`, which puts the messages on an Azure queue. `AddMessages` is called whenever I have `MyData` objects which should be added to the queue. This can be any number of objects (used in several clients). `ToBinary()` serializes a `MyData` object.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPortions<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int portion)
{
   double length = (list.Count() / (double)portion); 

   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
         yield return list.ToList().Skip(i * portion).Take(portion);
   } 
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    IEnumerable<int> list = Enumerable.Range(1, 25); 

    foreach (var item in GetPortions(list, 10))
    {

    }
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately, `list.Count()` will enumerate `list`, and cause the exception.